# Share IValueConverter between Wpf and Xamarin Forms

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

I'm creating solution which will contain Wpf application project and also Xamarin Forms mobile app. Some common part of my code I'm putting in portable class library. Is it possible to create ValueConvertes so that I can use them in Wpf and Xamarin forms?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's unfortunately not possible.